# Run Live Mesh 2010 on older Windows XP machine?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-vista, windows-live-mesh

I want to get Live Mesh 2010 working on my Windows XP machine.

https://www.mesh.com/welcome/default.aspx

Are there any tricks that would allow me to fool the app into thinking my XP machine is Windows 7 (or Vista)?

It's an old PC, I can't justify upgrading it just yet for one piece of software.

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the description?

> Note
>
> Windows Live Mesh can be installed on computers running Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, and Mac OS X version 10.5 or later. It can't be installed on computers running Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, or Windows Home Server version 1.

[Reference](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh-devices-sync-upgrade-ui)

Answer (score 1):

This is a quote from another discussion in another forum:

> I recently discovered windows live
>   mesh and my initial thoughts are quite
>   possitive.
>
> However when I tried to run it on my
>   windows xp pro 64 machince I
>   discovered that this is not an
>   operating system supported by live
>   mesh.
>
> The work around was simple. Download
>   the 64 bit vista installer and the run
>   it using the command prompt and with
>   the following parameter:
>
> livemesh.exe -force

Download:
[here](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh?os=other)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is impossible, with Vista> having a completely new networking system, which it probably relies on.

Comment: Or just MS wanting to get people off XP.